# Strange Javascript behaviour when reassigning function of a class

Tags: javascript, html, function

There is a class Car and a class Bot. Bot takes a car object as constructor argument. Also, Car class has setCollisionHandler function which behaves like object.setActionListener(func) in JavaScript. This setCollisionHandler reassigns function onCollision in car object.

Output:

```
Bot.onCollision: undefined
Bot.myfunc: 23
```

Expected output:

```
Bot.onCollision: 23
Bot.myfunc: 23
```

Why is this happening?

```html
<script>
  class Bot {
    constructor(car) {
      this.x = 23; // some parameter
      this.car = car;
      this.car.setCollisionHandler(this.onCollision);
    }
    myfunc() {
      console.log('Bot.myfunc: ' + this.x); // Bot.myfunc: 23
    }
    onCollision() {
      console.log('Bot.onCollision: ' + this.x); // Bot.onCollision: undefined //why is it undefined??
    }
  }
  class Car {
    onCollision() {
      console.log('Original Car.onCollision'); // never executed as expected
    }
    setCollisionHandler(func) {
      this.onCollision = func;
    }
    updateCarPosition() {
      // more code
      this.onCollision();
      // more code
    }
  }
  car = new Car();
  bot = new Bot(car);
  car.updateCarPosition();
  bot.myfunc();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because `this` when called refers to the `Car` not the `Bot` as you expect.

It's easy enough to fix by using `bind` to bind the function back to the instance of the object you expect:

```
this.car.setCollisionHandler(this.onCollision.bind(this));
```

```html
<script>
  class Bot {
    constructor(car) {
      this.x = 23; // some parameter
      this.car = car;
      this.car.setCollisionHandler(this.onCollision.bind(this));
    }
    myfunc() {
      console.log('Bot.myfunc: ' + this.x); // Bot.myfunc: 23
    }
    onCollision() {
      console.log('Bot.onCollision: ' + this.x); // Bot.onCollision: undefined //why is it undefined??
    }
  }
  class Car {
    onCollision() {
      console.log('Original Car.onCollision'); // never executed as expected
    }
    setCollisionHandler(func) {
      this.onCollision = func;
    }
    updateCarPosition() {
      // more code
      this.onCollision();
      // more code
    }
  }
  car = new Car();
  bot = new Bot(car);
  car.updateCarPosition();
  bot.myfunc();
</script>
```

Further reading: [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 0):

That's because when you are calling 
`this.car.setCollisionHandler(this.onCollision);` the function are loosing the context. It is pretty common situation in JS

You may do the following here:

`this.car.setCollisionHandler(this.onCollision.bind(this));`

or

`this.car.setCollisionHandler(() => this.onCollision);`